# typescript import without as

Tags: typescript, import

I want to use the import keyword in my ts files:

```
import Koa from "koa"
const app = new Koa()
```

So I have setup the following options in my tsconfig:

```
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

But this transpiles to:

```
const koa_1 = require("koa");
const app = new koa_1.default();
```

resulting in:

```
TypeError: koa_1.default is not a constructor
```

It works when I import like this:

```
import * as Koa from "koa"
```

transpiled to:

```
const Koa = require("koa");
const app = new Koa();
```

How can I use the `import Koa from "koa"` syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to set `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to true in your compiler options. Or you can `esModuleInterop` which automatically sets `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` when `module` is set to `commonjs`.